# Module not found: Can't resolve './pages

Tags: reactjs

I'm having issues that I've never experienced before. Recently, I've started a new project with create-react-app however, I'm shown an error:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './pages/' in '
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz4p5.png)

I've tried different file paths but in my previous projects this is the path that has worked but for some reason, it doesn't work anymore.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './pages'

function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <Home />
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'

export const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

If someone could help that would be great! I've been trying to solve this for the past 3hrs and nothing has come from it! Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's inside the pages folder? Do you have file called pages? you should separate your Home component as a separate file

Comment: Hey @FahimHoque inside my pages folder is two files Home.js and About.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're code is failing is because the `pages` folder doesn't have an `index.js` file. If you want to import the `Home` page component directly from the `pages` folder, without using `import Home from "./pages/home"` syntax, you'll have to create an `index.js` file, inside the `pages` directory, that exports the home component, like this:

"./pages/index.js"

```js
...
export * from './home';
export * from './someOtherPage';
....
```

Then, in App.js, you can import the Home component like this:

```js
...
import { Home, SomeOtherComponent } from './pages';
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes so I forgot to add the index.js file in the pages folder. I also tried 

export { Home, About} but that didn't work but yours did! Thanks again!

Comment: Anytime! BTW, the code that you were trying to use ( `export { Home, About }...`) will only work when Home and About components are being exported from the same file :)

Comment: Seems so simple! haha its been 3 months since I last touched React so I put it down to being out of touch :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `'./pages/Home'` instead of `'./pages'`

Answer (score 0):

What you've imported as `./pages` is actually the folder when you need to import the file itself. So it should be something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './pages/Home.js'

function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <Home />
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```